# How to extract a single polygon from a shapefile which has multiple sub-polygons

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have downloaded the official boundary Shapefile for all municipalities in the Canadian Province of Ontario.  I wish to extract the boundary polygon for one county from this file and convert it to a form that can be used on Google Maps.  I am running on Ubuntu Linux and when I try to use GRASS it dumps me out to a command line.  I am therefore totally lost.

Comment: Your title and body don't match. A "sub-polygon" would be a polygon subpart (e.g. an island in an archipelago). Yet you seem to want a single polygon from the set of distinct polygons in a shapefile.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the shapefile to QGIS by dragging and dropping it (the *.shp).
2. [Select](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=select#selecting-features) the polygon you want to extract.
3. Right click the layer in the layer tree and: Export - Save Selected Features As - Save as a geojson format file.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried installing QGIS on my Ubuntu Linux computer.  It created an icon for Grass.  When I tried opening that icon it opened a command line window.  So what do you mean by "dragging and dropping"?  The Government site I was retrieving from had options to generate KML and GeoJSON but when I selected those options I just got Conversion Failed

Comment: GRASS and QGis are different softwares. You've got a QGIS tag to your question so you are asking for a QGIS solution

Answer (score 0):

1. As you want to use your boundary polygon in Google map, it seems you want to make a Google My Map. So, you need to upload your polygon as a KML file in Google My Map.
2. So, my suggestion is that [download Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/about/versions/#download-pro). It's light weight and free. Then drag drop your shapefile there.
3. Go to your desired polygon and then right click of mouse. Then select "Save places as" option. A window will appear to save your file in your PC. select the folder and give a name. Lastly, you will see "Save as type" options, which is below file name option. Select KML as your file type. Now you are ready to drag drop your KML file to Google Maps or anywhere else you want.

Comment: Thank you.  I could not get the source site to provide me with a KML.  It had an option but when I clicked it just displayed "conversion failed"  I tried loading the Shapefile into Google Earth Pro.  I cannot see any way to select a polygon.  The tool turns the picture of the globe to highlight the province of Ontario but it does not show anything within the boundary of the province.  How do I select the polygon if I cannot see it?

Comment: Welcome on your success to install google earth pro. You can follow this to do further: Import shapefile into Google Earth Pro
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b01vGwmI8HI